# Two conflicting shoulda matchers allow_value expressions are both passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

`:speed`is simply a numeric model attribute.

Both of these are passing:

```
    it { is_expected.to allow_value( '1').for(:speed) }
    it { is_expected.not_to allow_value( '1', 'fff' ).for(:speed) }
```

With a minor change, the second one is not passing:

```
    it { is_expected.to allow_value( '1').for(:speed) }
    it { is_expected.not_to allow_value( '1' ).for(:speed) }
```

Apparently, if there's a single passing value in the `not_to allow_value` expression the whole list of values passes.

I'm not quite understanding if it's working as intended and I'm doing it wrong, or if it's a bug.

It seems like it's a bug according to how the documentation explains it.

Comment: Which version of shoulda-matchers are you using?

Comment: You might need to provide more code, like the full spec, class, and error message.  I can't reproduce this issue using shoulda-matchers version 3.1.1: it works as expected.